# Measure Preserving Diffeomorphism of $\mathbf R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A homeomorphism $h:\mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R^n$ will be called ***measure preserving*** if $\mu(h(A))=\mu(A)$ for all Lebesgue measurable sets $A$ in $\mathbf R^n$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

It is well-known that the linear isomorphisms $T:\mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R^n$ which are measure preserving are precisely those with determinant $\pm 1$.

I am wondering if the converse is true:

> **Question.** Are all measure preserving homeomorphisms $h:\mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R^n$   which fix the origin are necessarily linear?

I was getting nowhere. So I replaced "homeomorphism" with "diffeomorphism" in the above. And for simplicity let's assume we are only interested in orientation preserving diffeomorphisms. Then the question becomes:

> **Question.** Let $f:\mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R^n$ be an origin fixing diffeomorphism such that its Jacobian has constant determinant $1$.
>   Then is $f$ necessarily linear?

Can somebody help me with the above? Thanks.

**EDIT.** The answer to the above question is "no". For consider $f:\mathbf R^2\to \mathbf R^2$ defined as $f(x, y)=(x, y+g(x))$ where $g:\mathbf R\to \mathbf R$ is any smooth map taking $0$ to $0$.
This example was provided by a professor at my insititute.

Comment: first idea: try differentiating $f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)$

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be surjective?

Comment: @zhw. Yes. By a diffeomorphism I mean a bijective smooth map with a smooth inverse.